# Reading exact columns of a text file and putting the values/text into a vector

Tags: c, arrays, file, text, multiple-columns

I'm building a code on which I have to read a text file with many types of data. Here is a part of the file:

```
1000000 923475248-18 Ramiro A. Xavier
999999 923501748-58 Ramiro A. Wolski 
999998 923517472-32 Ramiro Q. Wollinger
```

(It has 1000000 lines)

And after reading it, I have to select the kind of data I want to work with, and I have to sort it, alphabetically or in crescent/decrescent order in case of the numbers.

I already have the code to sort it (Bubble Sort), but in my code, I have to type the data myself. So my question is:

How do I read one specific column of this file and save it's content on an array?

I'm working on this as a project, and I am not allowed to use C++ language or much complex structures such as ("cout <<, buf, aot, tmpline")

I managed to read the file and print what's in it with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c;

    fp = fopen("list1000000.txt","r"); 
    if(!fp)
    {
        printf( "Error");
        exit(0);
    }
    while((c = getc(fp) ) != EOF) 

    printf("%c", c);

    getch(); 
    return 0;
    fclose(fp);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,
  Eduardo

Comment: Have you played with the shell sort command?  It's pretty awesome and would work with the kind of data.

Comment: Grab a line and do a sscanf.  sscanf(line,"%d %d %s %s %s\n",&var, &var,fn,mn,lastname);

Comment: I don't think I understand the restrictions you are being forced to work under. Specifically, what would be considered "*complex structures*". Can you clarify this in your post?

Answer (score 0):

1. Read a line in.
2. Scan it for the various parts (numbers, first name, middle initial, last name, etc.)
3. Put the elements into a structure that holds all of them. Put pointers to the structures in an array.
4. Using one or more elements as keys, sort the structures as needed.